# Does this code take full advantage of Spark's distributed computing and functional programming paradigms

Tags: scala, functional-programming, apache-spark

I have an array of n tuples: (Key, Data). Both are custom defined objects. In each Data object, I have a String field query.

If there is a query, that string will not be equal to my default value "".

What I want is the proportion of the array that has valid queries.

This is the code I have right now:

```
val proportion = (inputArr map {case (key, data) =>
  data map (d => if (d.query != "") 1 else 0) sum
} sum) / inputArr.length
```

Is this optimal code is is there an even better way of accomplishing what I want to do? Also, I know Spark automatically parallelizes reduce, but my IDE suggested I replace reduce (_ + _) with sum, but that will still automatically be distributed and computed, right? Also, I'm fairly new to the functional approach, so please let me know if I'm doing something inefficiently.

Updated:

```
val betterProportion = (inputArr count { case (key, listDatas) =>
  (listDatas count (data => data.query != "")) > 0
}) / inputArr.length
```

Is this better code?

Updated:

```
val betterProportion = (inputs filter { case (key, listDatas) =>
  (listDatas count (data => data.query != "")) > 0
} count()) / inputs.count()
```

This code was updated to use the original RDD instead of a subset array to address the issue about there not being a length function on RDDs.

Comment: Using filter and then count is a more elegant and readable way of doing the same thing

Comment: `inputArr.length`? Are you sure it is Spark? RDDs have no `length` method.

Comment: Oh that could be a problem. For my testing purposes I did RDD take 20 which returned an array, but eventually I will need to find the proportion of the entire RDD. What do you recommend for that?